# R Simmer: "no arrival running" errors when specifying a non-standard routing algorithm

Tags: r, queueing, event-simulation

Consider the system and routing algorithm specified below:
[Image of the system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVXHy.png).
Let us first define some attributes which will be useful in the simulation:

```
library(simmer)
library(parallel)
library(simmer.plot)
#############################
d<- 2
#############################
set.seed(1337)
sim<-simmer()

#let's say the system has 1000 servers/respective queues
queues<- vector(length=1000)
for (i in 1:1000) {
  queues[i]<- paste0("q_",i)
}


queueing_system <- trajectory() %>%
  set_attribute("X", function() rexp(1,100)) %>%
#"e_i", i in {1,2} will be the number of the queue sampled
  set_attribute(paste0("e", 1:d), function() sample(1000,2)) %>% 

#d_i will be the size of these respective queues

  set_attribute("d1", function() get_server_count(sim,queues[get_attribute(sim,"e1")]))%>%
  set_attribute("d2", function() get_server_count(sim,queues[get_attribute(sim,"e2")]))
```

Now, let us define the routing algorithm and the trajectories thereafter.

We can try expressing the routing algorithm entirely within the clone function as follows:

```
number_of_clones <- function(a,b)
{
if(function() a+b==0){2}else{1}}

routing_logic <- function(a,b,c,d)
{
  if((a>=1 & b=0)|(a=0 & b>=1))
  {
    trajectory()%>%
    select(function() queues[get_attribute(sim,c(c,d)[which(c(a,b)==0)])])%>%
    seize_selected()%>%
      timeout(function() get_attribute(sim, "X")*(rpois(1, 10)+1)) 

  }
  else if (a>=1 & b>=1){
    trajectory()%>%
    select(function() queues[get_attribute(sim,sample(c(c,d)),1)])%>%
    seize_selected()%>%
    timeout(function() get_attribute(sim, "X")*(rpois(1, 10)+1))

  }
  else if (a+b==0){
    n <- trajectory()%>%
      select(function() queues[get_attribute(sim,c)])%>%
      seize_selected()%>%
      timeout(function() get_attribute(sim, "X")*(rpois(1, 10)+1))
    m <- trajectory()%>%
      select(function() queues[get_attribute(sim,d)])%>%
      seize_selected()%>%
      timeout(function() get_attribute(sim, "X")*(rpois(1, 10)+1))
    list(n,m)
  }

}

#trajectory is then expressed as
queueing_system %>%
  clone(number_of_clones(get_attribute(sim,"d1"),get_attribute(sim,"d2")),routing_logic(get_attribute(sim,"d1"),get_attribute(sim,"d2"),"e1","e2"))%>%
synchronize(FALSE)%>%
  release_selected()
```

We now receive the following problem:

```
> queueing_system %>%
+   clone(number_of_clones(get_attribute(sim,"d1"),get_attribute(sim,"d2")),routing_logic(get_attribute(sim,"d1"),get_attribute(sim,"d2"),"e1","e2"))%>%
+ synchronize(FALSE)%>%
+   release_selected()
Error: there is no arrival running
```

I reckon this has something to do with calling the functions in the conditions of my "if" and "else if" statements though am unsure as to what I am doing wrong, exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `get_attribute` cannot be called directly. Instead, it must be placed inside a function that is called during the simulation.

Comment: I see, however calling 
`queueing_system %>%
  clone(number_of_clones(function()get_attribute(sim,"d1"),function()get_attribute(sim,"d2")),routing_logic(function()get_attribute(sim,"d1"),function()get_attribute(sim,"d2"),"e1","e2"))%>%
  synchronize(FALSE)%>%
  release_selected()` leads to error `Error in *tmp* >= 1 : 
  comparison (5) is possible only for atomic and list types`, though this might be an error in how I coded in the system

Comment: Actually, it seems that no matter how I try it, there is an issue in the logic when dealing with get_attribute. For instance, I changed a and b to be "d1" and "d2" respectively and, for every call of a and b in the trajectory above, I instead made a function(){get_attribute(sim,a)}-type argument. I am given an error: `Error in (function() get_attribute(sim, a) >= 1 & function() get_attribute(sim, : operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types` so I reckon it is not me specifying the logic incorrectly but that R is incorrectly reading the function(){get_attribute} args

Comment: Most `simmer` activities accept a function as argument. This is the same as passing a pointer to a function, a callback, in C, for example. You are instead actually **calling** `number_of_clones`, so you are evaluating the function and passing the result, not the function itself.

Comment: I see. Calling   `clone(function()number_of_clones(function()get_attribute(sim,"d1"),function()get_attribute(sim,"d2")),function()routing_logic(function()get_attribute(sim,"d1"),function()get_attribute(sim,"d2"),"e1","e2"))` now gives error `Error: clone: '...' is not a valid trajectory` so I presume I just made an error specifying a trajectory. This does solve the issue of as to how I must specify the attributes in the routing algorithm, though

Comment: I'll rephrase the above: most `simmer` activities accept a function for *some* of their arguments, not all. Please, do read the documentation.

Comment: I have read the documentation, however I found it somewhat vague in specifying exactly when a function is/is not allowed as an argument (I assumed "most" allowed functions in all places, like in your original wording). For example, "clone" says n can be a function, though perhaps you mean to imply the second argument cannot be. Rewriting the if/else if arguments with branch (which is explicitly shown to accept functions in the option parameter) seems to lead to proper results.

Comment: Or, I should say that now going through the documentation in R, it is made specific as to which functions take functions (and where), though https://r-simmer.org/articles/simmer-03-trajectories.html can be a bit vague in that regard

Comment: Sorry, but the documentation is pretty clear. See for instance `?clone`: "n: number of clones, accepts either a numeric or a callable object (a function) which must return a numeric"; "...: a number of optional parallel sub-trajectories (or a list of sub-trajectories). Each clone will follow a different sub-trajectory if available". The first arguments clearly specifies it accepts a function. The rest of them, not. What is vague there?

Comment: I corrected myself to say the R documentation was not vague, rather the "advanced trajectory usage" page was somewhat, though I should have been looking at the R documentation as my primary resource, regardless